# Run Python script through the day only at times stored within a database

Tags: python, mysql

Run Python script through the day only at times stored within a database.

I have a database that indicates start times:

```
ID  Starttime
1   12:00
2   13:00
3   15:40 
4   18:00 
5   19:45
```

I would like to execute that script ONLY at those times. The python file is in my windows server. There are two options I can think of.

Implement an `if` statement within my code that says `if(time=now)` then do the rest of the script. But this would require me still running the script every 5min
The other option I can think of is somehow setting the task scheduler to pull the times from the database in the morning and setting those times to run - to which I have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can read https://pypi.python.org/pypi/schedule.

Here is an example:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

`schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)` is your want.

Comment: so would i need to dynamicly update the file everyday doing a while loop adding the following schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job). does this get added directly to the python file i want to run